# How to find a second specific word after a first specific word in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string

I've looked at similar cases but they are not the same.

I've got a pandas frame. Each row is a study. In a particular column, I need to find out how many times a specific word, i.e. bed, comes after another specific word, i.e. home.

I need to find out how many cases in the pandas frame this situation happens.

I've seen questions that ask about extracting whatever text comes after a specific word but not a case like this. I'm assuming this might be regex but can't figure out how to do it.

My code to create a sample dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'whereabouts': ['in bed at home', 'at home in bed',
                            'in school in class', 
                            'at home in bed', 'at home in yard'] 
            'last_name': ['James', 'Ellen', 'Alex', 'Tomas','Rick']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['whereabouts', first_name'])
print(df)
```

I need to be able to find the number of instances in the whereabouts column that the string "bed" comes after the string "home".

Comment: Can you add the code to generate a sample dataframe please?

Comment: @DebraDaly Added code as requested. Using Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: @JoelK, could you add the code to generate the sample dataframe without reading a file, so that somebody trying to work on your question can have the same type of dataframe loaded as you do? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for details.

Comment: @VirtualScooter I'll try. I'm not a coder so this is all new to me. I just want to know how to find the number of instances of a word that come after another word in each row. Anyway, I'll look at the document you showed me and try to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: @JoelK. How about just including a couple of dataframe records (like the output in Jupyter Notebook of `athritis_data.sample(10)`? That will give a sample of 10, with the headers.

Comment: @VirtualScooter I redid the code and text to make it clearer. Gave a simple example. I hope this helps! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try this:

```
import re
df['col'] = df.whereabouts.str.contains(r'.*home.*bed.*', flags=re.I)
```

Output:

```
    whereabouts         col
0   in bed at home      False
1   at home in bed      True
2   in school in class  False
3   at home in bed      True
4   at home in yard     False
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the number of times that "bed" appears after "home" in the `whereabouts` column, use the following code.

The function `second_after` returns `True` if
the input `text` contains the `second` word after the `first` word (`rfind`
finds the last `second` word). This can be applied to the `whereabouts` column
of the dataframe, generating a new column `results` for easy cross-checking.

Finally, the method `.sum` is applied to the `results` column, counting all the
`True` values ("like 1") and not `False` values ("like 0"):

```
import pandas as pd

def second_after(text, first, second):
    """ Check if second word after first word in text. """
    if not first in text:
        return False
    return text.rfind(second) > text.find(first)

raw_data = {'whereabouts':
            ['in bed at home', 'at home in bed',
             'in school in class', 'at home in bed', 'at home in yard'],
            'first_name': ['James', 'Ellen', 'Alex', 'Tomas', 'Rick']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(raw_data)
df['results'] = df.whereabouts.apply(lambda x: second_after(x, 'home', 'bed'))
print(df.results.sum())
print(df)
# 2
#           whereabouts first_name  results
# 0      in bed at home      James    False
# 1      at home in bed      Ellen     True
# 2  in school in class       Alex    False
# 3      at home in bed      Tomas     True
# 4     at home in yard       Rick    False
```

Comment: Works great; just what I needed! Thanks!